# Can we use Selenium or any other jars to get network response and validate

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, querystringparameter

I have a requirement here that I need to verify the network response values using selenium & java.

It would be great if there is any code that could help me out.

The action that I want to perform (which is needed to be automated) is

1. load the application https://www.ancestry.com
2. press F12 and go to network tab when application is loading
3. select a respective network containing b/ss
4. click on it and get the values in the query parameters

I have highlighted them in the below image

Note: I need to perform this action for every click event that happen after the application is loaded.

Is this possible in selenium

[image: Network Request]

[image: Network Request]

This is the code that I tried to get the values recorded am I doing it right please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.ancestry.com");
    //capture(driver);
    driver.quit();
}

public static void capture(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
    OutputStream logfile = new FileOutputStream(new File(new 
    File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\log.txt"), true);
    PrintStream printlog = new PrintStream(logfile);
    LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
    for (LogEntry entry : logs) {
        if (entry.toString().contains("\"type\":\"Img\""))
            System.out.println(entry.toString());

        printlog.append(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.toString() + " "
                + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        printlog.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        printlog.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    printlog.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Siyadh, welcome to StackOverflow. Please include what you have tried so far, read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Brydenr will add the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get all the network logs using browser mob proxy

```
private static BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
public webLib(String browser) {
        logReport.logMethodStart("Launch Application");
        Proxy seleniumProxy = null;
        proxy.start();
        seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            try {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        new File(".").getCanonicalFile() + seperator + "WebDriver" + seperator + "chromeDriver.exe");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
            options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

        }

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (driver != null) {
            logReport.logStep(Status.PASS, "Browser launched successfully", driver);
        }

    }
```

You can reffer the following site
https://www.swtestacademy.com/webdriver-browsermob-proxy/